# Question Palindrom Number Javascript is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I don't understand why dosen't work good.
So, in Visual Studio Code running, but in LeetCode after i press the button to Run code it will give me one error

```
const isPalindrome = number => {
const palindrom = number.split('').reverse().join('');

return (palindrom === number) ? palindrom : false;}
```

Error : [image]

Visual Studio Code running :

[image]

Comment: if for some reason you are unsure number is getting passed as a string argument, you should patch it by appending .toString() after the two references to number.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you will pass an integer. cast or convert the passed parameter to string then would work.

```js
const isPalindrome = number => {
const palindrom = number.toString().split('').reverse().join('');

return (palindrom == number) ? palindrom : false;}

const res = []; 
res.push(isPalindrome(1221));
res.push(isPalindrome("1221"));
res.push(isPalindrome("av"));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: `isPalindrome(1221)` returns false, return true

Comment: @Samathingamajig you are right! i will updated

Comment: "1221" is not === 1221

Comment: @James and  Samathingamajig you are right. I fixed . Thanks!

Comment: It's works, but why? I found multiple example with .toString with .splite work, but I don't understand how it's works?  Oke you take a number, after force them toString :s

Edit: I think, this number from function it will be an string, and where you put the condition to see if (number == string) it will be return true

Comment: @LegeNNND `split()` is a String function. If you would pass a integer then you will get the error what you are published. That the reason why you have be sure that the passed parameter is  a string.

Comment: and for convert / cast int you can use toString() or String(var)

Comment: Yes yes I understand , thanks all !

Comment: @LegeNNND Welcome :-)!